# Json API to DataTable vb net asp Deserialize

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, serialization, datatable

I need to convert the result of an `IRestResponse` response performed with RestSharp.

It returns me the following error:

> At least one element of the source array could not be reduced to the target array type.

Tips?

I write the code below:

```
 Dim client0 = New RestClient("https://api.factorialhr.com/api/v1/core/teams/")
        client0.Timeout = -1
        Dim request0 = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
        Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        request0.AddHeader("x-api-key", xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
        Dim response0 As IRestResponse = client0.Execute(request0)
        Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(response0.Content)
```

What I receive as a response to the call is this:

```
[
{
    "id": 36122,
    "name": "Back Office",
    "employee_ids": [
        499272,
        503226,
        539829,
        729420
    ],
    "lead_ids": [
        539829
    ]
},
{
    "id": 36123,
    "name": "Installatori",
    "employee_ids": [
        499263,
        499264,
        499265,
        499269,
        499270,
        499274,
        499275,
        499279,
        499282,
        499283,
        499284,
        499285,
        499288,
        499294,
        499297,
        499299,
        508690,
        572661,
        598771,
        598777,
        617926,
        641372,
        649757,
        660408,
        685130,
        700772,
        738345,
        750255,
        756124,
        775905,
        804415,
        815284
    ],
    "lead_ids": []
},
{
    "id": 36125,
    "name": "HR",
    "employee_ids": [
        489538,
        807485
    ],
    "lead_ids": []
},
{
    "id": 36126,
    "name": "Edilizia",
    "employee_ids": [
        499268,
        499271
    ],
    "lead_ids": []
},
{
    "id": 36127,
    "name": "Magazzino",
    "employee_ids": [
        499273,
        499276,
        499286,
        499290,
        499298
    ],
    "lead_ids": [
        499298
    ]
},
{
    "id": 58184,
    "name": "Ufficio tecnico",
    "employee_ids": [
        499278,
        499280,
        499292,
        499293,
        499295,
        499296,
        627481
    ],
    "lead_ids": [
        499293
    ]
},
{
    "id": 58469,
    "name": "Fotovoltaico",
    "employee_ids": [],
    "lead_ids": []
}]
```

---

***EDIT:***
this is the code I receive from the call.
The one posted previously was by postman:

```
[{""id"":36956,""name"":""INSTALLATORI"",""employee_ids"":[499852,507630,507797,507806,527793,527869,529021,552669,632190,632283,641422,641430,653119,671805,672237,675800,678893,699318,738118,787870,807347,808077,817154,825297,827029,832745,860124,860556,864280,865201],""lead_ids"":[]},{""id"":36957,""name"":""MAGAZZINO"",""employee_ids"":[499844,499856,711627],""lead_ids"":[]},{""id"":36958,""name"":""Customer care"",""employee_ids"":[516292,577013,627479],""lead_ids"":[516292]},{""id"":36960,""name"":""MARKETING"",""employee_ids"":[],""lead_ids"":[]},{""id"":36961,""name"":""HR"",""employee_ids"":[585682],""lead_ids"":[]}]
```

Comment: Looks like your Json has array properties.  Looks like you're attempting to Deserialize a multi-layer data structure into a single layer data table.  Maybe have a look at Edit>Paste Special>Paste Json as Class.  The read up on how to deserialize to a List(of T)

Comment: try using a DataSet in place of datatable. I find EVEN for a single table, newtonsoft likes MUCH better if you use a dataset in place of a datatable. The resulting dataset is really just a collection of tables, and you can freely use/get the first table in the dataset table collection with mydataset.tables(0) anyway.

Comment: What do you a table for? Your data mostly contains ids that are not user friendly, you can not use it  for UI

Comment: @Serge  - what do you mean the data is not user friendly? the data is rather quite simple, and for each of the rows, there is child repeating data. See my 2nd edit below - I show that with a simple conversion to a data table, then even the repeating child data can be displayed with little effort. To be fair, I used a gridview, and probably should have used a treeview - but the child data is only in a sense one child table deep, so for simple display, we just convert the child repeating data to a string with "," in it. But yes, I do agree 100% that display of data is not much help.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I mean instead of Id it should have the name of employee. This is what I call user friendly interface. I am not even talking about possibility to spoil all data

Comment: Very well (my bad)- I did miss understand - and I agree 100% with you -  I miss read that we can't work with the data, or it not useful - but without question from a UI point of view? You are 100 if not 200% correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as suggested, try using a dataset. (I don't need or suggest often to use a dataset when  datatable (one table) is a better choice - ONLY exception to this rule is when using json + newtonsoft - the dataset tends to work more often).

And good for you to share the json data - so we can try it.

Looking at your data?

Ok, I'll just paste into a notepad.

So, our markup is this (button + grid)

```
    <div style="padding:35px">

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Parese Jason, get data" Width="152px" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="20%"></asp:GridView>

    </div>
```

And code is this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strBufJSON As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\test7\jdata5.txt")
    strBufJSON = "{""myroot"":" & strBufJSON & "}"

    Dim rstData As New DataSet
    rstData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(strBufJSON)

    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we now get this:

[image]

So, we have to do a bit more, to get that other data. But the above is a start.

## Edit: What about the other repeating data?

Well, if you look close at rstData in above?

You actually see that the two repeating columns ARE placed and ARE part of rstData In fact, the data types are int64() arrays!!!

So, to display that data? lets tweak our GV a bit.

So, GV becomes this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" width="48%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name"    />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("empID") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="60" Rows="3" Style="width:100%">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="leadID" HeaderText="lead id's"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And now our code becomes this:
(we just add 2 more text columns to rstData), such as:

```
    Dim rstData As New DataSet
    rstData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(strBufJSON)

    Dim rst As DataTable = rstData.Tables(0)
    rst.Columns.Add("empID", GetType(String))
    rst.Columns.Add("leadID", GetType(String))
    ' convert the 2 int[] array to strings

    For Each OneRow In rst.Rows
        OneRow("empID") = String.Join(",", CType(OneRow("employee_ids"), Int64()))
        Dim leadAr As Int64() = OneRow("lead_ids")
        OneRow("leadID") = String.Join(",", CType(OneRow("lead_ids"), Int64()))
    Next
    GridView1.DataSource = rst
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

And now we get/see this:

[image]

## Edit2: Some better and more resilient parsing

Ok, so the poster has follow up with some additional sample data.
The above first examples? By me adding the { root etc.?

Well, the above much assumes that we are and will try to de-serialize the json into a class. But, the original json is really formatted as a array.

As a result? One will have much more luck using the json "parser".

I suggest this code, and it works for the last posted data.

And the code in some ways is less confusing anyway. Like parsing xml? Lets use the Newtonsoft "parser" - (and we should have perhaps made that our first choice - but then again, this is SO - and so answers and time taken here is a gift horse anyway.

So, our new code is thus this:

```
    Dim strBufJSON As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\test7\jdata6.txt")
    Dim rEmp As JArray = JArray.Parse(strBufJSON)

    ' we NOW have free use of this "array" of information.

    ' EXAMPLE print first row id and name
    Debug.Print(rEmp(0).Item("id"))
    Debug.Print(rEmp(0).Item("name"))
    Debug.Print(rEmp(0).Item("employee_ids").ToString(Formatting.None))


    ' lets biuld a table from this parsed data.
    ' this ALSO shows how to get/view/list the columns (name of keys)
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    For Each jProp As JProperty In rEmp(0)
        rstData.Columns.Add(jProp.Name)
    Next

    ' now send all rows in array to rstData
    For Each jRow As JToken In rEmp
        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstData.NewRow
        For Each jColumn As JProperty In jRow
            OneRow(jColumn.Name) = jColumn.Value
        Next
        rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Next

    GridView2.DataSource = rstData
    GridView2.DataBind()
```

our markup is this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
      width="48%"  CssClass="table" />
```

And our results are this:

Output Window:

[image]

And the grid view shows like this:

[image]

So, while perhaps a bit more looping, I suggest the above, since we parse out into a "j-array", and from that point on, you can quite much do what you  wish with the data.

Comment: Hi! thank you very much for your advice! I tried but it comes out error ... Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Additional text found in the JSON string after finishing the deserialization of the object. Path '[0].id', line 1, position 7.'

Comment: I would only need the id and name fields

Comment: The above sample code? I took your posted json data and pasted into a note pad - look close at above code. I take the "returned" json, and then wrap around that result this:         strBufJSON = "{""myroot"":" & strBufJSON & "}"
         ----    so see how I added a {} around the json, and also added myroot:  --- so look at the posted code again. If your posted json data is correct, then the above code will work.

Comment: the code I published I copied from postman.
Now I try to see what to extract me directly from RestClient

Comment: response0.Content:  https://justpaste.it/1q8rh         ---- sorry for link, the space here was not enough

Comment: If i use the your first solution, this error comes out. System.InvalidCastException: 'At least one source array element could not be reduced to the target array type.'

Comment: I'm really sorry about my low experience, it's the first time I use Json.
I've been doing a lot of tests for 2 days but I can't understand the problem.

Comment: Ok, so we have the response text. Say in a string var called strResponse. So, we then wrap around that "response" like this:   strResponse = "{""myroot"":" & strResponse & "}"    ------ so, we then use strResponse like this:   rstData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(strResponse)  ------ so look at my sample code again. We assume a return value from the api - that you have working (the hard part!!!).

Comment: still error...
is it normal that in the string that makes me as an answer, there are 4 quotation marks?  ""id"":36956,""name"":""INSTALLATORI"",""employee_ids"": ..........

Comment: I have big news, I discovered that if I delete the number contained in the lead_ids of the customer care category, everything works ... unfortunately I can not leave the field empty, what can cause this problem? but if I remove everything else and leave only the Customer care category with also the field lead_ids filled in, everything works. Could it be that there are json length limits?

Comment: I don't believe that the actual data has those double quote marks. Remember, the hover, or debug.print outputs extra " around strings. It might be, but I much doubt it. In your original json, it did not have those extra quotes, and it works just fine.   Unless the sample data and what your API web is returning is different? This should work. And no, I doubt the issue is the length of the json unless it really large.

Comment: Please, last try... can you try with this data?
Json: https://jpst.it/2XyU5
routine: https://jpst.it/2XD35

Comment: Take a look at my edit and 3rd sample code - you should find it much more useful, and it should work much better for your needs.